# Visual Studio 2015 HRESULT: 0x80070005 / E_ACCESSDENIED on SharePoint Empty project creation

Tags: 2016, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 and SharePoint 2016.

When I'm trying to create a new project via `File > New > Project > SharePoint 2016 - Empty Project` in Visual Studio 2015, I'm receiving the following error message and the project is not created:

> Access denied (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

[image]

Comment: is that error occurred only when you create a sharepoint project ? or any project?

Comment: How about opening visual studio in admin mode ? I.e right click visual studio and click on run as admin and check ?

Answer (score 1):

Per [site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43182648/1539718), You should be able to address the ACCESSDENIED exception following these [steps](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31188/access-denied-error-1.html):

- Make sure all the instances of Visual studio are closed.
- Go to
  %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_****
- Delete the file
  privateregistry.bin

**Note**: The link and version above indicates Visual Studio 2017, but this is applicable to 2015 as well.

Comment: Did this resolve your issue?